# How do I kill applications or windows by title?

Tags: macos

I am a windows bod most of the time but now there are macs in the mix and I need to support all the blocked apps our company deems unfit to run on their system. In Windows I used a small app I wrote that runs in the background and just kills any window containing a specified title. Could someone please help with a bit of script that would do the same in OS X?

Comment: That must be quite a big list of titles and must take some maintaining...

Answer (score 0):

Can't make a script for you, but maybe it would be helpful to include[`killall`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/killall.1.html) in your search. "The killall utility kills processes selected by name..."

Comment: yeah saw that but you need to know the proc name and i wana kill by window title. but thanks for the help.